# How to Crop and Save Jpg In Photoshop WIthout Save As?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save, crop

Hello I have a lot of jpg images that I need to crop and save. The problem is after Im done cropping the jpg I try to save but the pop up "Save As" dialog keeps popping up. And even if I decided to use the pop up and do a save as jpg it doesn't overwrite the old jpg and instead just makes a copy. Because of that I have to delete the old jpg file and delete the word "copy" which takes up a lot of time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

All I want do is just crop a jpg image and do command save and that's it the file is updated.
please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Crop preferences....

This may be due to the set **preferences for the crop tool**. With the **Crop Tool** selected, be certain the `Delete Cropped Pixels` item in the **Control Bar** **IS** checked.

[image]

If this item is NOT checked, the file will no longer be a flat single layer file.

By retaining cropped pixels, you introduce a level of transparency. And since jpg does not support transparency, you can't then mere "save" to the jpg format.

---

Another possibility.............

[image]

Viewing your screenshot, the only layer is "Layer 0" and is not a **flat background layer**. The item above would account for this, but if the preference is *not* the issue....

....the "jpg" may not *really* be a jpg.

You may not be getting a flat background layer because the image is *actually* a png file or some other format with merely the *suffix* in the file name changed to "jpg". *Actual* jpgs open in Photoshop with one, locked, layer titled "Background".

[image]

If you wish to merely "save", **flatten the image** first. After flattening the image, "save" should work as you are expecting.

---

**NOTE** JPG is a **lossy** format - meaning to save file size (kb), the jpg format *throws out data*. Saving any jpg *as a jpg* reduces image quality. The more often you do this the worse the image gets.

Comment: it worked thank you. Yes most of the jpg files I open has layer named background with a lock. Is there a way to have the images already flattened when I open them? Or there a hot key to flatten the layer quickly?

Comment: @jr005 I've edited, please reread.

Comment: Now it is working perfectly! Thank you sooo much! I really appreciate it.